# flask-sqlalchemy adjusting data modeled from DB?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to take care of null values in my model. For example, a simple Car model:

```
class Cars(db_a.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'
    car_id = db_a.Column('car_id', db_a.Integer, primary_key=True)
    year = db_a.Column('year', db_a.Integer)
    make = db_a.Column('make', db_a.String(50))
    description = db_a.Column('description', db_a.Text)
```

If description is Null, I want to return "Unknown." I know I can default the column in the table configuration, but I was hoping to handle it in this model.

I have done a lot of searching but not found anything that works. Any suggestions would be appreciate.

Thank you